# What should I do when I press the button in the pos recorder scene to record and save it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, record, tracking, playback, leap-motion

I am doing hand tracking through leap motion at Unity.
And I'm trying to record and play certain tracking through hand tracking, but things aren't working out.
I'm trying to use unity 6.8.1 and 2021.3.22f1.

I open the 'pose recorder' scene built into the tracking folder and press the 'record pose' button in it to complete what needs to be recorded and saved.
If you look at the inspector of the button, there is an interaction button (script) and I put a specific function in On Press(), but it won't play.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbutR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8I0B.png)

Comment: unity 6.8.1? they didnt make a 6.8.1 only 5.6.7 and then to 2017 .. why would you use 2 versions especially lets say its a unity 5 .. which is very incompatible without a lot of work with 2021?